# Web browser Password recovery Tool for Windows

Tags: windows, password-recovery

I'm looking for a Tool to recover lost/forgotten password of any Website, including popular Web sites, like Facebook, Yahoo, Google, and GMail, as long as the password is stored by your Web Browser.

- Easily recover passwords
- Save passwords into a text/ html / csv / xml file
- Recover your lost password of any Website
- Free or Paid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebBrowserPassView is a password recovery tool that reveals the passwords stored by the following Web browsers: Internet Explorer (Version 4.0 - 11.0), Mozilla Firefox (All Versions), Google Chrome, Safari, and Opera. This tool can be used to recover your lost/forgotten password of any Website, including popular Web sites, like Facebook, Yahoo, Google, and GMail, as long as the password is stored by your Web Browser.

After retrieving your lost passwords, you can save them into text/html/csv/xml file, by using the 'Save Selected Items' option (Ctrl+S).

[image: Web Browser Password Recovery]

**System Requirements And Limitations**

- This utility works on any version of Windows, starting from Windows 2000, and up to Windows 10, including 64-bit systems. Older versions of Windows (Windows 98/ME) are not supported, because this utility is a Unicode application.
- Currently, WebBrowserPassView cannot retrieve passwords from external hard-drive (Except of Firefox Web browser). Support for that might be added in future versions.
- On Internet Explorer 7.0-9.0, the passwords are encrypted with the URL of the Web site, so WebBrowserPassView uses the history file of Internet Explorer to decrypt the passwords. If you clear the history of Internet Explorer, WebBrowserPassView won't be able to decrypt the passwords.
- On Google Chrome - passwords originally imported from Internet Explorer 7.0-9.0, cannot be decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's not a single tool for all browsers.
However, storing passwords in a browser seems a bad choice anyway if you have a look at how easily they can be retrieved.

I suggest using a password safe such as [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) and the auto-type feature instead of storing passwords in the browser.

### Firefox

I use [Nirsoft Password Fox](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html). Note that it comes in 32 Bit and 64 Bit and you have to use the version that matches your Firefox.

✓ Easily recover passwords: run the tool, all your passwords are displayed.

✓ Save passwords as: Text, HTML, CSV, XML (press Ctrl+A to select all)

✓ Recover lost passwords of any website: of Firefox

✓ Free or paid: free (closed source)

### Internet Explorer

I use [Nirsoft IE PassView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html). It's free. Same author as before.

✓ Easily recover passwords: run the tool, all your passwords are displayed.

✓ Save passwords as: Text, HTML, CSV, XML (press Ctrl+A to select all)

✓ Recover lost passwords of any website: of Internet Explorer

✓ Free or paid: free (closed source)

### Chrome

The same author has also written [ChromePass](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html), but I have no experience with it.